Is LoRa Suitable for Short-Range, Real-Time Data Transmission in Residential Environments?
I'm working on a project where I need to wirelessly collect data from utility meters in European residential homes. The setup involves a point-to-point connection between a meter reading device and a controller, which might be a few walls away within the house. The system should operate without internet connectivity, and the pairing process between the transmitter and receiver should be straightforward. Ideally, the transmitter should also be energy-efficient.
Initially, I considered using WiFi for this project. However, I’ve had poor experiences with WiFi signal penetration in basements and the dependency on a router poses issues, especially if the router is relocated or malfunctions.
I've been researching LoRa and LoRaWAN and am considering using it for this purpose. Although I don't require long-range communication spanning kilometers, I do need reliable connectivity within a single-family home. The most critical requirement is to transmit meter readings or power values every second. Occasional packet loss is acceptable, but the system should generally function reliably. I estimate the data load to be a maximum of 30 bytes per second, although I can manage with less if necessary.
I've ordered some hardware to begin testing in rural areas, and based on my understanding of the technology, I’m optimistic that this could work. However, there are a few concerns I haven't been able to fully address:

Urban Performance: While I'm starting tests in rural areas, I’m unsure how well this would work in an urban setting. Can anyone share their real-world experience with LoRa in such environments, particularly indoors?

Scalability: As more LoRa devices are added over time, how might this impact performance? Is there a way to ensure a minimum data transmission rate in a congested environment?

ISM Band Limitations: Are there any specific limitations regarding the allowed usage rate on the ISM band that I should be aware of for this application?


Lastly, if there’s a more suitable “plug & play” technology that could meet my requirements, I’m open to alternative suggestions.

What is your scenario? Will this be deployed by the utility, or is this something the end user will buy and install themselves? Why do you need so frequent updates? Why do you need so much data? Who needs the data? The end user? The utility? Where is all that data doing to be stored?

@jcaron: This is an end-consumer device, so intended to be installed and used by non-professionals. The realtime data is needed to manage a local energy storage system's action, i.e. a battery with a controller (= the receiver). This is why LoRa seems intuitive first, as no Wifi fiddling is involved and the devices can be installed a few walls apart.

I’m afraid you are probably waaaaay off on what LoRa can do.

Indoor: LoRa doesn’t like it (like all other wireless technologies, line of sight makes all the difference). A single wall can be the difference between signal or no signal.
Reliably: no.
Every second: no.
30 bytes per second: no.
In ETSI territory: even worse. The ISM band limitations are quite a handicap.
Scalability: the duty cycle limits are so low that you won’t have issues there. Except you can’t use confirmed packets if you have many meters on a single gateway.

At SF12 (the modulation with the best SNR threshold), 30 bytes take 2 seconds to transmit! And ETSI rules only allow 0.1 or 1% duty cycle, depending on the channel. Max EIRP is very low.
Lora works well for infrequent, best effort, very low bandwidth, outdoors, battery powered scenarios.
Sending a meter reading twice a day, not worrying if packets get lost and you end up with readings only half of the time (because you are sending cumulative data, not deltas)? Possible (but some locations just won’t work). Real time data very second? Most definitely not.
What is your plan? Have one gateway in each home? With Internet access? Always connected and working? I’m sorry to say you live in the land of the unicorns if you think this is viable.
Also, what kind of utility are you measuring? Are you able to get power or does the meter need to run on battery? Can you use the medium to send back data (powerline communication for electricity supply, for instance)?
As you mention power, I suppose it’s electricity. Send data back up the grid using PLC. That’s what “smart meters” do (but, as far as I know, with much, much lower frequency). You don’t want to have to rely on some internet connection you don’t control.

Thanks @jcaron for the very clear and elaborative answer. The duty cycle alone puts a spoke in my wheel. Yes, my goal is to have one gateway inside the home that connects to a reader (measuring energy), but not necessarily with internet access. Running on battery would be very nice, but it could have a power supply as well. PLC is not guaranteed to work across the home. And Wifi is too much fiddling... Do you have any wireless technology recommendation you have that makes keeps the "Plug & Play" aspect I had in mind with LoRa?
